# problem with timeout in netsnmp lib

Tags: python, net-snmp

I have simple example:

```
import netsnmp
var = netsnmp.Varbind('ifHCInOctets','0')
res = netsnmp.snmpgetnext(var,Version = 2,DestHost='localhost',Community='public',Timeout=1000000)
print res[0]
```

```
 time python2 test.py
```

show me:

```
real    0m4.086s
user    0m0.073s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Why 4 seconds = 1000000 ? snmpd server not work on localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass `Timeout=?` you are setting the maximum time that snmp's internal select loop should wait before registering a timeout.  Setting this to `1000000` means "wait 1 million microseconds", which is 1 second.

However there is also a `Retries=?` argument that specifies the number of times the snmp client will re-attempt the request after a timeout, so for `Timeout=1000000, Retries=0` select will attempt only 1 request and timeout in 1 second.  If `Retries=1` it will try twice and timeout in 2 seconds.

So depending on the combination of Timeout and Retries you will see different amounts of delay.

The default number of Retries is 3, so 1 try + 3 retries of 1 seconds each = 4 seconds.